# How can I customize a modal window using Wicket 1.5?

Tags: wicket, modal-dialog

I´ve already found this answer ([Can the Wicket modal window be customized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385314/can-the-wicket-modal-window-be-customized)) but it´s not suitable for Wicket 1.5. Can anyone please tell me how can I apply my own styles to a Wicket Modal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create you own stylesheet and use set `setCssClassName()` ?

If you want to fully override all of the modal window css override the `newCssResource()` to return your own css resource. All its resources are in `/wicket-extensions/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/modal/res/` including its stylesheet `modal.css`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What I did was creatin my own modal.css then setting setCssClassName("modal.css") for the modalWindow object and response.renderCSSReference("css/modal.css") on the renderHead method.